# How to add google analytics (GTAG) to my python dash app?

Tags: python, google-analytics, plotly-dash

I have a gtag.js which contains my tracking code.

Google says to add this to the top of my , how can I dot his for my dash app please?

I've tried adding it as gtag.js under /assets but did not work

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*****-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-******-1');
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to accomplish this in at least two ways:

1. Override the index string:

   > The following was copied from the docs and updated with the question's JavaScript.

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.index_string = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*****-1"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'UA-******-1');
        </script>
        {%metas%}
        <title>{%title%}</title>
        {%favicon%}
        {%css%}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>My Custom header</div>
        {%app_entry%}
        <footer>
            {%config%}
            {%scripts%}
            {%renderer%}
        </footer>
        <div>My Custom footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
'''
```

2. Override the `Dash.interpolate_index` method:

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html


class CustomDash(dash.Dash):
    def interpolate_index(self, **kwargs):
        # Inspect the arguments by printing them
        print(kwargs)
        return '''
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>My App</title>
                <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
                <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-*****-1"></script>
                <script>
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                    gtag('js', new Date());

                    gtag('config', 'UA-******-1');
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>

                <div id="custom-header">My custom header</div>
                {app_entry}
                {config}
                {scripts}
                {renderer}
                <div id="custom-footer">My custom footer</div>
            </body>
        </html>
        '''.format(
            app_entry=kwargs['app_entry'],
            config=kwargs['config'],
            scripts=kwargs['scripts'],
            renderer=kwargs['renderer'])

app = CustomDash()
```

See [the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) and [sislvacl's answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/tracking-application-analytics-with-google-analytics/38946) in the Plotly forums for more depth.

Comment: Just, when using interpolate_index, keep a close eye on replacing single curly braces in tracking code snippets (provided in javascript) with doubled curly braces (to make string interpolation in Python possible).